# Update the settings of a class after construction

Tags: python, class, constructor

I got the following structure:

First, a config class:

```
class Config:
    def __init__(self, config_path='./configs') -> None:
        file = open(config_path, 'r')
        self.config_path = config_path
        self.config = yaml.safe_load(file)
```

The purpose of the class is basically to load a .yaml file and set the configurations specified in that yaml as an attribute. The idea, is that other classes can inherit from that, like so:

```
class SARSA_TileEncoding(Config):
    def __init__(self, env: gym.Env, config_dir='./configs') -> None:
        super().__init__(SARSA_TileEncoding, config_dir)
        self.tile_encoder = TileEncoding(env, self.config)
```

With this, I can now simply use `self.config['parameter']` in the class, for example:

```
class SARSA_TileEncoding(Config):
    def __init__(self, env: gym.Env, config_dir='./configs') -> None:
        super().__init__(SARSA_TileEncoding, env, config_dir)
        self.tile_encoder = TileEncoding(env, self.config)

    def do_something(self):
        for n in self.config['n_times']:
            print('Hello')
```

However, the config might get updated after construction, which is not a problem, since the parameters are accessed on the fly. But, as you can see the class `SARSA_TileEncoding` has the attribute

```
self.tile_encoder = TileEncoding(env, self.config)
```

which also relies on the config. The issue now is, that if the config gets updated, this class `TileEncoding` will still uses the values from the config at construction. Is there a good way to solve this, i.e., also update the config from `TileEncoding`?

Comment: Look up "composition over inheritance". There is really no reason for your class to _inherit_ from Config. Is it an UberConfig object?

Comment: Is there a singular config all encodings should read from?

Comment: No, the config from the encoding depends on the class where it gets used, in that case it depends on the ```SARSA_TileEncoding```, that is why they share the same config. @roganjosh I am not sure if UberConfig object is meant as sarcasm, but I just found it convenient that the class loads the config automatically at construction (with inheritance), but I  will look into your suggestion.

Comment: @kklaw I guess you could call it sarcasm but I was being genuine. I just couldn't think of a better name to illustrate the point I was trying to make sorry

Comment: The point is that inheritance is supposed to represent the "IS-A" relationship: a subclass is a more specific kind of the parent class. E.g. `class truck(vehicle):`. Don't use it for "HAS-A" relationships, e.g. `class vehicle(engine):` is wrong.

Comment: BTW, you're calling `super().__init__(SARSA_TileEncoding, env, config_dir)` with too many arguments. You don't pass the class name as an argument, and the superclass only expects one argument, `config_path`.

Comment: You can't use `open()` with a directory, only individual files.

Comment: I simplified the code, and removed some parts to make it easier to read, but you are absolutely right. I forgot to double check if it would still work after simplification.

Comment: Neither inheritance nor composition are appropriate in this context. The config is a global, shared resource. It shouldn't be the job of client objects to manage this resource in any way. The config belongs in a separate module that can be imported wherever it's needed. Doing things that way eliminates any problems with synchronisation. If the config is loaded, updated and accessed via a single interface, all clients will see the same values (which implies the clients should never cache values locally without good reason).